# Force CMake target_link_libraries to fail when adding nonexistent target

Tags: c++, cmake, target-link-libraries

CMake has an irritating default (I presume, I see nothing magical in my CMake config, but I could be wrong since I know very little about CMake) behavior that he silently ignores when you add a target to your project even if that target does not exist, for example:

> project(StackOverflow)
>
> // another CMakeLists.txt
>
> project (Stuff)
>
> target_link_libraries(Stuff
>      PUBLIC    StackOverlow )

Is there a way to force CMake to check that all projects you link in `target_link_libraries` must exist?

Comment: What is the non-existent target here in your example? The syntax for `target_link_libraries()` in your example is incorrect. Specifically, the first argument *must* be an **existing** target, or you will receive an error. You haven't created a target `StackOverflow` either.

Comment: @squareskittles sorry, I reduced my real CMakeLists.txt too much, thank you for bug report :)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible for CMake to fail if you link ALIAS targets. For example

#### In first CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(StackOverflow STATIC lib.cpp)
add_library(StackOverflow::StackOverflow ALIAS StackOverflow)
```

#### In second CMakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(Stuff PUBLIC StackOverflow::StackOverflow)
```

CMake will fail with an error if StackOverflow::StackOverflow is not defined.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#alias-targets

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks.  It also explains why most project use this kind of alias.

Answer (score 1):

In CMake, you do not link projects to other projects. Instead, you link **targets** to other targets.

CMake targets are **only** created via a few commands (such as `add_library`, `add_executable`, and `add_custom_target`). The `project` command does not create a CMake target, it merely declares a project.

Furthermore, the [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command accepts the following arguments after the scoping keyword:

- A library target name
- A full path to a library file
- A plain library name
- A link flag
- A generator expression
- A `debug`, `optimized`, or `general` keyword

It does not accept *project names*, although if you put a project name, it will instead look for a CMake **target** or library file on your system *with that name*.

To get to the root of what I believe you're asking: If you provide link-item name to `target_link_libraries()` that does not match an existing target, the command will simply search for a **library file** of that name instead.

To check if a target exists *before* trying to link it, you can do:

```
if (TARGET StackOverflow)
    target_link_libraries(Stuff PUBLIC StackOverflow)
endif()
```

I suggest reading through the linked `target_link_libraries()` documentation if you want more details about what this command does.

Comment: ah, this is definitely not ideal... and yes you are right, I never considered the "fallback" (or default) that target_link_libraries will look for library instead of failing.

Comment: also now I found this feature request for what I want: https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2019-February/068983.html

 looks ignored. :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The active CMake issues can be found [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues), although from a quick search I didn't see anything related to this issue. CMake has made incredible efforts to maintain backward compatibility, and I think a change like this would break that. Perhaps, they could add a CMake policy to optionally produce a warning when linking non-target link items...

Comment: I do not see how adding new builtin function (target_add_targets) would break bw compat, but tbh like I said CMake is mostly a black box to me.